# Swift: Setting View on top of SceneView not working

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set up a layout where a Map is placed on top of the SceneView. When the app builds, the set up flashes for a second, and then the SceneView takes up the whole screen, completely hiding the other two views.

After moving the SceneView on the left hand menu and moving it back, the text started appearing but not the black background.

(I've got constraints set for the Scene View to take up the whole screen, and some constraints (right and bottom) on the Map too.

Why is it not working?

EDIT: It started working after I deleted the view and added it back in, but not sure why. @El Tomato says SceneViews always overlaps other views. Is this true (i.e. by accidentally getting it to work, am I utilizing a bug)?

[image]

Comment: It's not going to happen.  The scene view will always come on top of others.

Comment: Where have you seen this documented? I just got this working a few minutes ago but not sure what I did... I've also seen this in other apps too.

Comment: Also, plz provide reason for downvote.

Answer (score 0):

It is doable. I'm doing it currently with an app I am using, but the difference is that I didn't set up the ARSceneView in the Interface builder, but I added it to fit the whole screen programmatically. I have some buttons that were added through the interface builder, and I added a label with a background now just to make sure it works similarly to how you want it.

I will post some images:

[image: Interface Builder]

Here i simply have the view controller with some (bad looking buttons) in the stack View as well as the label with a red background. The ARSceneView is added in the my ViewDidAppear function and takes up the whole frame.

[image: UI Debug]

This picture is from the screen while the app is executing (Debugging the UI). As you can see, the Label with the background as well as the buttons I've added all show.

I also have 2 buttons that are showing as well (the white and red circle) and these were added programmatically and were brought to the front.

My suggestion is to try and add the ARSceneView programmatically, maybe it doesn't work otherwise. Or you can try to outlet all your views and bring the Map View and the Label to the front using bringSubviewToFront.